# Confused about Isometric Immersions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry book, on page 125, he has the following discussion:

Let $f:M^n \rightarrow \overline{M}^k$ be an immersion where $k \geq n$.

Then for each $p \in M$, there exists a neighborhood $U \subset M$ of $p$ such that $f(U) \subset \overline{M}$ is a submanifold of $\overline{M}$.

He also says that we identify $U$ with the image $f(U)$ and each vector $v \in T_qM$ with its image $df_q(v) \in T_{f(q)}\overline{M}$.

> I am confused about two things here. Firstly, why does this neigbhorhood $U$ exists, and secondly, is $f:U \rightarrow f(U)$ an isometry? I find it odd to say that we are identifing $U$ with $f(U)$ if it is not an isometry.

Answer (score 1):

The neighborhood $U$ exists because of the inverse function theorem. We're using the *local diffeomorphism* $f$ to identify $U$ with $f(U)$. There are no mentions of Riemannian metric, so why are you bringing in the notion of isometry?

Comment: I'm bringing in the notion of Isometry because we want to identify them. Usually identifications are done with some sort of morphism to make those objects be the same in some sense.

Comment: Also, we can't really use the Inverse Function Theorem here because we only know that the differential at every point is injective. But the dimensions of the manifolds are not the same so you can't say that the differential is invertible, which is a requirement to apply the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: The diffeomorphism is the morphism. OK, it's a matter of terminology. The canonical immersion theorem (which follows from the inverse function theorem) is what you want. Or look up the rank theorem. These are all totally standard.